# role="alert" is only working for the first time

Tags: html, accessibility, alert, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have added the following piece of code to make screen reader read the alert message:

```html
<aside aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" role="alert" ng-show="login.hasWarning();" translate="{{message}}"></aside>

<form>
  <!--form content-->
</form>
```

It works perfectly for the first time, however when I commit the error again, it doesn't reads the updated error message again. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you pushing the same error message again? As in, pushing "Error 101" the first time, then pushing "Error 101" the second time?

If so:
JAWS/VoiceOver/NVDA only read updates to the live region. If you replace text with identical text, it doesn't count as an update.
Replace the text with an empty string before pushing the new error message. Note that JAWS may say "Blank", depending on the browser and user settings.

Comment: Do you have any idea why all the major screen readers ( JAWS/VoiceOver/NVDA ) choose to do so? And is there any work around, say like adding random empty spaces at the end of message etc. so that screen readers read it again ?

Comment: Because that's the WAI-ARIA spec. (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live) The SR is reading changes to the live region. If your update isn't a change, then the SR doesn't read it. Adding empty spaces to the beginning and end of the message might work with VoiceOver, and probably won't work with JAWS. If you're comfortable with JAWS potentially saying "blank Error 101" instead of "Error 101", running $("[aria-live]").text(""); $("[aria-live]").text("Error 101"); will at least be read.